# Context overrides context_object_name

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and pretty lost on how to approach this problem.

Views.py:

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
model = CustomUser
context_object_name = 'profile_detail'
template_name = 'user_profile_templates/profile_detail.html'

def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    followers_var = request.user.motivators.all()

    if len(followers_var) == 0:
        is_following = False

    for follower in followers_var:
        if follower == request.user:
            is_following = True
            break
        else:
            is_following = False

    number_of_followers = len(followers_var)

    context = {
        'number_of_followers': number_of_followers,
        'is_following': is_following,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'user_profile_templates/profile_detail.html', context,)
```

So the problem is that I can't use context_object_name or 'object.var_name' in my template I guess that context that I defined in my get method is responsible for that. I've read somewhere that we should not use get() method in DetailView class, but I don't know what to do instead, should I use View and go from there? RequestContext? How would you refactor this whole class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `DetailView`, you can put the code that deals with context in `get_context_data`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
   ... # your code
   context["number_of_followers"] = number_of_followers,
   context["is_following"] = is_following,
```